# creating user table in MySql populated with only the Facebook ID?

Tags: mysql, facebook, security

I would like best practices and advice about creating a new 'user' table in MySql that will NOT store the reg user/pass in it, but will store the facebook ID that will be given to me by Facebook.

Normally, I'd worry about random Hashing everything in there, but... do I still need to do that? if there's NO personal information tied in to their facebook ID, i don't see a reason to change anything...

so, Stack Overflow MySql Geniuses, tell me the best way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your table would be like this:

I use this for my authentication for "login with facebook" (and other providers) app

```
CREATE TABLE authentications (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provider` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `access_token` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `secret` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expires` int(12) DEFAULT '0',
  `refresh_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`user_id`,`provider`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `default_authentications` (`id`, `provider`, `uid`, `access_token`, `secret`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `expires`, `refresh_token`) VALUES
(10, 'twitter', '754569028', '897234097-FxwID1nybWTIMmZs1hngsaWwedsfsfx7uiwxMwfU4s', '7uc1vzBAL9rA8h38asdfasfasOzeJkyt1jU1Zj4c', 1344632332, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Normally, I'd worry about random Hashing everything in there, but... do I still need to do that? if there's NO personal information tied in to their facebook ID, i don't see a reason to change anything...

So your basic question is, whether it’s considered “safe” from a privacy protection standpoint, to use the Facebook user id to identify an account in your system?

If you don’t tie any other (personal) information to it, then about the only info that the hacker who gets access to your database will get is, *“1234567890123 has connected to Youhan’s app/website using their Facebook account.”* Up to you to decide, how “bad” this would actually be.

If you have any doubts, you could use the `third_party_id` Facebook provides (in the Graph API user object and the FQL user table) instead of the Facebook user id – *“A string containing an anonymous, but unique identifier for the user. You can use this identifier with third-parties.”*

This `third_party_id` is tied to your app – every app will get it’s own third party id from Facebook for the same user account, so the only way to track that back to the actual user is if an attacker actually manages to get your app’s credentials or a valid access token into his hands.

Comment: ha! i want to accept both your answers :) - Thank you so much!